# How can I change the order in which constraints are evaluated

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table like the following

```
create table myTable (
    id uuid primary key,
    ref  uuid references otherTable(id),
    constraint myConstraint check (someFunction(ref))
);
```

Here I have two potential failure :

- ref doesn't exist in otherTable
- somefunction return false

My problem is that someFunction will fail if `ref doesn't exist`. I end up with the same error in both case. Is there a way to have the referential integrity checked before the other constraint ?

Comment: You can't. SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one.

Comment: Just a thought. Maybe you can place the second constraint into a post-insert trigger.

Comment: You could set `ref` to `NOT NULL`. Not really sure what your restrictions might be on this idea.